# how to install readline-devel without root

Tags: bash, quick-install-package

Struggling with it for days...
I tries to visit the official website of readline, but did not see the devel version,
and searched many pages, just found readline-devel.rpm, and I an a root user, so I can't install it with yum.
Any help would be appreciated~

Comment: Did you try creating a non-root user to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your only option is to use rpm2cpio as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/100189/rpm-without-root), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/209808/how-can-i-install-an-rpm-without-being-root) and [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html).

The best course of action is to request the system administrator to either install the package for you or grant you sudo rights for you to install the application.